How do I change characters used nvim diagnostics signs?
I'm using ale for diagnostics, but I want to change how it shows signs. It seems the setup is different for nvim since ALE's docs say they don't have any configuration:

When |g:ale_use_neovim_diagnostics_api| is 1, the only other setting that will be respected for signs is |g:ale_sign_priority|. ALE's highlight groups will and other sign settings will not apply when setting signs through Neovim's diagnostics API. See |diagnostic-signs| for how to configure signs in Neovim.

I added this block based on :h diagnostic-signs to my init.lua:
vim.diagnostic.config{
    virtual_text = false,  -- floating text next to code is too noisy.
    underline = true,
    signs = {
        text = {
            [vim.diagnostic.severity.ERROR] = "",
            [vim.diagnostic.severity.WARN]  = "",
            [vim.diagnostic.severity.INFO]  = "",
            [vim.diagnostic.severity.HINT]  = "",
        },
        linehl = {
            [vim.diagnostic.severity.ERROR] = 'ErrorMsg',
        },
        numhl = {
            [vim.diagnostic.severity.WARN] = 'WarningMsg',
        },
    },
}

ALE's diagnostics in my left margin still use letters:

If I :luafile % my init.lua, then the signs use symbols:

I'm also using these plugins to setup my lsp (using luals for lua):

lspconfig
mason
mason-lspconfig

The above vim.diagnostic.config setting successfully removes the floating text from lsp warnings, so it's partially working but not for signs. Disabling these other lsp plugins doesn't help.
Am I putting my diagnostic settings in the wrong place?

:echo g:ale_use_neovim_diagnostics_api
1
:version
NVIM v0.10.0

